# Replacing regex match in pandas column with modified regex

Tags: regex, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace a regular expression match with modified regular expression.
Following is the column in my DataFrame.

```
    df['newcolumn']
    0    Ther was a quick brown appl_product_type in ("eds") where blah blan appl_Cust_type =("value","value")
    1    Ther was a quick brown appl_product_type = ("EDS") where blah blan appl_Cust_type =("value","value") 
    2    Ther was a quick brown appl_product_type in ("eds") where blah b                                     
    3    Ther was a quick brown appl_product_type in = ("EDS") where blah blan appl_Cust_type = ("value")     
    4    Ther was a quick brown  where blah blan appl_Cust_type                                               
    Name: newcolumn, dtype: object
```

i want to replace every occurrence of strings like "appl_product_type = ('EDS')' to 'upper(appl_product_type) = ('EDS')'

i am using following code but getting error

```
    newcolumn.replace(value='upper\[\w]+\s+[in=]+[\s+\([\"\w+\,+\s+]+\)', regex='[\w]+\s+[in=]+[\s+\([\"\w+\,+\s+]+\)')
    error: bad escape \w at position 7
```

is there a way to solve this ?? Please Help.

Comment: Why are you using `\w` in your replacement ? You should be using the group match instead

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things -

- you cant use \w in your replacement value and expect it to know what to fill in
- your regex as is, is badly formatted. use `r''` to make simpler regex strings
- your question is unclear as you are asking one specific format while your regex is attempting to catch a lot more.

I have a slightly more clear solution to what you have attempted, but am unsure if this is exactly what you wanted given the ambiguity in you question. -

```
df['newcolumn'] = df['newcolumn'].replace({r'([\w_]+\s+(?:in|=|\s)+\(\"(?:\w+\"(?:\,)?(?:\s+)?)+\))' : r'upper(\1)'}, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the answer.It worked as expected.It's just that i don't understand what \1 in the replacement key is doing.I have edited the question .I only want regex to match the entire string and replace with upper(appl_product_type) = ("eds")

Comment: @deepakkumar thats not an issue, in a regex replace you can use `\1`, `\2` and so on as a substitute to that matching group in your regex. Since I surrounded the regex by `()` and that was the only matching group `\1` acted as a substitute for the whole regex match. I used a number of non-matching groups `(?:)` to avoid any confusion with groups